# How do I remove Unicode Characters from String?

Tags: php, python, regex, unicode

I need a **Regex** code to remove **Emoji**, **Symbols** ( basically any unicode character ) except Japanese, Korean, Chinese, Vietnamese , and any other languages that use unicode characters. The regex is going to be used for a php and Python server. I noticed that I'm having problem with iPhone users who uses Emoji keyboard to create some weird names.

So far I've tried a few regex but I couldn't find any proper one.
[image]

Below is my own text string which I use for testing. Please note that I have no idea what does the other english character means. If its a bad word please **change** it.

```
abcdefghij
klmnopqrst
uvwxyz
1234567890
한국 韓國
‎Công Ty Cổ Phần Hùng Đức
南极星 
おはようございます
============== Below characters should be detected by regex ========
™£¢£¢§¢∞§¶•§ª§¶
[]{}"';?><_+=-
()*&^%$#@!~`,.
4️⃣⌘
❤❣☁♫
```

Comment: [Wikipedia lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) the Unicode code points of a bunch of those characters.

Comment: You need to define exactly what you want to remove. The example does not tell it. This isn’t a simple alphabetic vs. non-alphabetic issue, since digits are not alphabetic and you do not specify whether non-alphabetic characters such as hyphen (-) and apostrophe (’) should be excluded, even though they appear inside names and other words.

Answer (score 0):

All symbols match `\p{S}` regex. You just need to be sure your PHP is in UTF-8 mode (whatever that means, I don't do PHP) – see http://php.net//manual/pl/regexp.reference.unicode.php – and for Python, you need an alternative regex library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 0):

You may find that regular expressions aren't the hammer for all nails. In this case you simply want to exclude characters, so it probably isn't.

In Python 3 the string [`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method would be useful: if you mapped the characters you want excluded to `None` they will indeed be excluded from the result.

Unfortunately this method only applies to ASCII strings, and takes a 256-character string as its mapping table. You couldl ,however, program a similar alogirthm yourself in Python, but it's not going to be as efficient.

PS: There are no "bad words" in your text.